# Find the value of $P(Y\leq0.25)$ and $P(X<0.5|Y>0.25)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume the following density function:
$
f_{XY}(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{x}& \text{if 0<y<x<1} \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

My Approach:

$
f_Y(y) = 
\begin{cases}
  \int_y^1 \frac{1}{x}dx& \text{if 0<y<x<1} \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Now, $ P(Y<0.25) = \int_0^{0.25}f_Y(y)dy$.

Am I correct?

My approach to the second question:

$
f_{XY}(X|Y) = 
\begin{cases}
   \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\int_y^1 \frac{1}{x}dx}& \text{if 0<y<x<1} \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Now,

$P(X<0.5|Y>0.25) = \int_{0.25}^{0.5}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\int_{0.25}^1\frac{1}{x}dx}dx$

Am I putting the limits right? If not, can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct, but you will need to actually evaluate the integrals you have written in order to obtain a probability.

Comment: Yes. I have done that also.